# View using Path

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm having an issue combining the use of taxonomy terms, URL alias patterns and views.

**Here's my setup:**

**1)** Taxonomy: A basic taxonomy, lets call it "Blog Tags". In here I have a term like Mountains. You can see the URL alias is shown here as "blog/tagged/mountains".
[image]

**2)** URL alias pattern: The pattern is "/blog/tagged/[term:name]".
[image]

**3)** View: This is a page view, that uses the path /newsroom/tagged/%. I have a contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID", that uses a specified "Blog Tags" taxonomy type.

*The following does not work:*

[image]

*The following does work*, but I cannot edit/translate my terms after applying:

[image]

Any idea what I can do differently to get this working?

Comment: Use TVI module, it should solve this.

Comment: @Kevin I was able to get the desired result using this module. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poster opted to use the [TVI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi), which greatly simplifies trying to get Views to display over the default term page(s).